# How to rename The Chosen

Tags: xcom-2, xcom-2-war-of-the-chosen

**Can I change the names of The Chosen in my game?**

On every playthrough, each Chosen is given a randomly-generated name and title, similarly to Uruks in *Middle Earth: Shadow of Mordor.*

[image: Assassin]

I do not care for the randomly generated names I have gotten, and would like to change them to something funny or memetic for the sake of adding comedy to my stream of the game.  **Is it possible to alter my save file so that I can manually customize the names in my current playthrough?**

Comment: I don't know about renaming them... but I just mentally referred to them as Assassin, Warlock, and Hunter - I don't think I actually noticed their names. 
 (I sometimes referred to the Assassin Chosen as *[Anglo-Saxon Expletive Deleted]* instead of Assassin...)

Comment: If it were possible, wouldn't you simply be able to find that name by opening your save file into a text editor?

Comment: @Jacob no thank you to the edit. I prefer to have the question reworded, in bold, at the tops of all questions I write, as a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For modifying your existing save file, I'll have to say 'maybe.' I do not know how to edit saves. They aren't entirely human readable after converting hex to ascii.

**If changing the Chosen names for the future is of any help, however, you can do that.**

You can modify the pool of names the Chosen names are selected from by changing the file at:

*\Steam\SteamApps\common\XCOM 2\XCom2-WarOfTheChosen\XComGame\Localization\INT\XComGame.int*

Or for other languages: *\Localization\(language identifier)\XComGame.(language identifier)*

Beginning on line 26573 is the list of all the possible first name prefixes, suffixes, last names, and nicknames for the three Chosen. Edit the text to whatever you want, and save the file.

I changed my assassin to this:

[image]